# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - how to access an array in a local json API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was able to import an api JSON locally using fetch, the api is available in [this](http://www.recipepuppy.com/api) url if you want to view it.

The problem is the following, when passing the state searchString I get the following error:

> 'TypeError: Can not read property' map 'of undefined'

I believe that is because I am importing the complete json object, whereas I need to access only key results.

```
File App.js

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchString: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('./recipes.json')
        .then(response => response.json()) 
        .then(json => console.log(json )) 
        .then(json => this.setState({ searchString: json }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container mt-10">
          <div className="row">
            <RecipeItem list={this.state.searchString}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

File RecipeItem.js 

const RecipeList = ({ searchString }) => {
    <div>
        <img className="card-img-top img-fluid" src={searchString.href} alt={searchString.title} />
        <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{searchString.title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">
                <strong>Ingredients: </strong>{searchString.ingredients}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
}

const RecipeItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="col-sm-3 mt-4">
            <div className="card">
                {props.list.map((searchString, index) =>
                    <RecipeList searchString = {searchString} key={index} />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecipeItem` component doesn't have the data when it's initially mounted, since you're doing a fetch call. So that's why you receive the error.

You can add a simple check if you have data and then do the map/filter/ or anything else:

```
{props.list && props.list.map((searchString, index) =>
   <RecipeList searchString = {searchString} key={index} />
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @chiril's answer, you need to check that the `searchString` list is actually an array when you set the state (so that the map function will be available):

```
    .then(json => this.setState({ searchString: json })); // check json object is an array
```

Comment: how could he do that?

Comment: I meant simply by console.log but you can do Array.isArray(obj)